# to find and replace the string in php

Tags: php

I have got a number of values by a foreach loop. Now I want to check each the values with a string.

My string is `"http://www.example.com/TantraProjects/Ranjit/nt_plugin"`

I have the values like written below:

```
http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch?scoring=d&partner=wordpress&q=link:http://www.example.com/TantraProjects/Ranjit/nt_plugin/

http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch_feeds?scoring=d&ie=utf-8&num=10&output=rss&partner=wordpress&q=link:http://www.example.com/TantraProjects/Ranjit/nt_plugin/

link:http://www.example.com/TantraProjects/Ranjit/nt_plugin/ - Google Blog Search
```

Now I want to change all the values, replacing `http://www.example.com/TantraProjects/Ranjit/nt_plugin` with `MY NEW PATH`.

How can I replace the string using php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)**

And please, use google, there are thousands of answers for that question online. :)

Also if you want to embed a links in URLs like that:

> http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch?scoring=d&partner=wordpress&q=link:http://www.example.com/TantraProjects/Ranjit/nt_plugin/

You need to use [urlencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on the URL you pass after `&q=`.

So basically:

```
$string = "http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch?scoring=d&partner=wordpress&q=MY_NEW_PATH";
$output = str_replace('MY_NEW_PATH', "link:".urlencode('http://www.example.com/TantraProjects/Ranjit/nt_plugin'), $string); //$search , $replace, $subject
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly by using [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) like this:

```
$findstr = "http://www.example.com/TantraProjects/Ranjit/nt_plugin";
$newstr = "new string here";
$newlist = array();

foreach($list as $item)
{
   $newlist[] = str_replace($findstr, $newstr, $item);
}
```